# Breaking out of the if-statement but not from the for-loop

Tags: c

How can I make this code only break out of the inner if-statement rather than stopping the for-loop?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int i,j;

    for(i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        if((i==2 || i==8 || i==4))
        {
            printf("\ni is %d\n",i);

            if(i==4)
            {
                printf("\ni is %d\n",i);
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                printf("\ni is not 4\n");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            printf("\nnext\n");
        }
        printf("\ngoes out of innner if\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This loop breaks out at `i=4`.  Is there any way to break out at `i-4` and continue with the for-loop until `i<10`?

Comment: You don't have an inner loop. An `if` statement isn't a loop.

Comment: Look at this code and tell me it's properly formatted.

Comment: you don't need a break in if loop

Comment: Where exactly do you want the flow of control to go after `break`?

Comment: I suggest using a `goto` statement instead of the break;-)

Answer (score 3):

I think the continue statement may be the thing you are looking for.

Also be aware that if() is not a loop.

Comment: No continue is needed here, since nothing is done after the if.

Comment: There is the printf("\ngoes out of innner if\n"); line :p

Comment: I'm glad you added that smiley, because of course I know that but thought it would be stupid and pedantic to mention it. I worry about the people who upvoted the comment.

Answer (score 2):

`if` statements are not loops; you don't 'break out' of them. When you use `break` inside an `if` statement, it will break out of the loop that directly encloses it (in this case, the for loop). `break` is not treated any differently inside an `if` block.

`if` blocks stop executing when they reach the end of the code that is inside them, or until they hit something that would cause them to stop executing anyway (such as `return`).

Answer (score 1):

I'd argue that it would be rather confusing, but you can use a loop that would be executed only once:

```
do {
    /* ... */
    if(i==4)
    {
        printf("\ni is %d\n",i);
        break;
    }
    /* ... */
} while(0);
```

Comment: There are times when this is a useful construct, and clearer than the spaghetti code or extraneous flags needed without it.